Swtich network to blast and sign message
Is it possible to switch network and sign a message using Nethereum?
So far I have tried following code:
var account = new Account(PRIVATE_KEY);
var web3 = new Web3(account, RPC_URL);


var signer = new EthereumMessageSigner();
var signature = signer.EncodeUTF8AndSign(message, new EthECKey(PRIVATE_KEY));

but as you can see there is no way of setting network for class EthereumMessageSigner
